# R: null value in list automatically removes element?

Tags: r, list

```
myls <- vector("list", length = 15)
for(j in 1:15){
  myls[[j]] = NULL
}
> length(myls)
[1] 7
```

I have a list with 15 elements, and I pass in a `NULL` value for all 15. However, the resulting list only has length of 7 `NULL` values? What happened to the other 8?

Comment: if you run `myls <- vector("list", length = 15)`, isn't it automatically creating a `list` of `NULL`s?

Comment: @sirallen Please add this as an answer. It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `myls[[j]] = NULL` removes the jth element from the vector. So on each iteration up to/including j = 8, `myls` is shortened by 1. After j = 8 iterations it has length 7 and the subsequent iterations do nothing.

If you want to set an element to `NULL`, use `myls[j] = list(NULL)`.